# java: "Unable to access jarfile ..."

Tags: java, linux, jar

I have downloaded RoboMind (http://robomind.net) and try to make it run on a Linux Mint12
Knowing that Min12 is not the newest release, I still would like it to run...

When I use the .sh file that comes in the pack I get an error:
"Unable to access jarfile ..."

if I type the exact same command at the same prompt, in the same directory, it works:

here is a copy paste from the commanline:

> > magnus@martin-HP-625 ~/Downloads/RoboMind $ ./robomind.sh

> > Unable to access jarfile RoboMind.jar

> > magnus@martin-HP-625 ~/Downloads/RoboMind $ cat ./robomind.sh

> > java -jar -Djava.ext.dirs=lib -Dsun.java2d.ddscale=true -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true RoboMind.jar

> > magnus@martin-HP-625 ~/Downloads/RoboMind $ java -jar -Djava.ext.dirs=lib -Dsun.java2d.ddscale=true -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true RoboMind.jar

> > ```
> > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> >     at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1076)
> >     at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1053)
> >     at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(SwingUtilities.java:1347)
> >     at robo.RoboMind.startGui(RoboMind.java:168) ... <snip>
> > ```

Now it works ... ?

Whats the difference?
I messed around with javapath etc. as suggested in other posts, but nothing makes any difference to the situation illustrated above.

Why can't the .sh script find the .jar file when the exact same command at the prompt have no problems?

Comment: have you checked the permission of your .sh file?

Comment: no problem with the permissions on the .sh file. It's executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give you the "solution", and I will let you discover "why".

Just launch:

```
# dos2unix robomind.sh
```

..after then it will work. If you do not have dos2unix installed, [`apt-get install dos2unix`](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/dos2unix)

Comment: I guess you insinuate that there are something funny with the <EOL>, <LF>, <CR> in the .sh file ... ?
I have tried to make sure there is not, by editing and re-saving in a Linux text editor.
But I haven't tried dos2unix, so let me do that and see if it helps.

regards /M