# getting "Error: Unable to access jarfile" when running from .sh file

Tags: java, shell

I am getting "Error: Unable to access jarfile" when running from .sh file. However I am able to run the command manually without any issue:
when I run ::

`[user@server ~]$java -jar lib/random.jar` it works.

However when I put this in a .sh file and run it fails ::

```
[user@server ~]$sh test.sh
Error: Unable to access jarfile lib/random.jar
```

**update**: test.sh has the same command I used initially. I also tried absolute path to jar file and no luck

Comment: Relative paths may work unexpected. Try absolute paths.

Comment: test.sh code listing?

Comment: Henry: its a typo. I just corrected it

Comment: What if you try `[user@server ~]$ ./test.sh`

Comment: Michael: same issue

Comment: An absolute path to the jarfile, or to java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java: "Unable to access jarfile ..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18943728/java-unable-to-access-jarfile)

Comment: absolute path to jar file

Comment: Try giving the absolute path to your java install aswell. You can test it by putting `echo /path/to/java -version` in your bash script.